# Problema con calculadora sencilla en Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

estoy tratando de hacer una calculadora sencilla en kotlin y aunque no me marca ningun fallo de sintaxis al ejecutarla me salta este error:

```
>   07/05 19:45:05: Launching 'app' on Pixel 3a API 30.
>     $ adb shell am start -n "com.example.calculadora/com.example.calculadora.MainActivity" -a
> android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>     Connected to process 6232 on device 'emulator-5554'.
>     Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the
> "Debugger" settings page.
>     I/ple.calculador: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
>     D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
>     D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
>     D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
>     D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
>     D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
>     W/ple.calculador: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z
> (greylist, reflection, allowed)
>     W/ple.calculador: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist,
> reflection, allowed)
>     D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>     E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>         Process: com.example.calculadora, PID: 6232
>         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.calculadora/com.example.calculadora.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3356)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3500)
>             at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
>             at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>             at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2049)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>             at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
>          Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>             at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)
>             at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:801)
>             at com.example.calculadora.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:38)
>             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
>             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7973)
>             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3329)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3500) 
>             at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
>             at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
>             at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
>             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2049) 
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523) 
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>             at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
>     I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6232 SIG: 9
```

Agradezco mucho de antemano a quien me pueda ayudar de alguna forma o decirme como solucionar el problema.
A continuación os dejo el código.

Kotlin:

```
package com.example.calculadora

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private var TextView_Resultado: TextView? = null
    private var EditText1: EditText? = null
    private var EditText2: EditText? = null

    private var boton1: Button? = null
    private var boton2: Button? = null
    private var boton3: Button? = null
    private var boton4: Button? = null
    private var boton5: Button? = null


    private var num1: Int = 0
    private var num2: Int = 0

    var resultado: Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        TextView_Resultado = findViewById(R.id.resultado) as TextView
        EditText1 = findViewById(R.id.EditText1) as EditText
        EditText2 = findViewById(R.id.EditText2) as EditText

        num1 = Integer.valueOf(EditText1?.text.toString())
        num2 = Integer.valueOf(EditText2?.text.toString())

        boton1 = findViewById(R.id.button1) as Button
        boton2 = findViewById(R.id.button2) as Button
        boton3 = findViewById(R.id.button3) as Button
        boton4 = findViewById(R.id.button4) as Button
        boton5 = findViewById(R.id.button5) as Button

        boton1!!.setOnClickListener(this)
        boton2!!.setOnClickListener(this)
        boton3!!.setOnClickListener(this)
        boton4!!.setOnClickListener(this)
        boton5!!.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when (v?.id) {
            R.id.button1 -> resultado = num1 + num2
            R.id.button2 -> resultado = num1 - num2
            R.id.button3 -> resultado = num1 * num2
            R.id.button4 -> resultado = num1 / num2
            R.id.button5 -> TextView_Resultado?.text = resultado.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se puede deducir gracias al LogCat y se describe aqui:

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

esto indica que tratas de convertir un valor no numerico a uno numerico, en este caso "" que no es numerico a un valor numerico lo cual no es posible y obtendrás el error NumberFormatException . El problema se produce en este punto:

```
    num1 = Integer.valueOf(EditText1?.text.toString())
    num2 = Integer.valueOf(EditText2?.text.toString())
```

Te sugiero agregar esta funcion para realizar la conversion a "0" como valor predeterminado en caso de que el valor no sea numerico:

```
fun String.intOrString(): Any {
    val v = toIntOrNull()
    return when(v) {
        null -> "0"
        else -> v
    }
}
```

y lo usarias de esta forma:

```
    num1 = Integer.valueOf(EditText1?.text.toString().intOrString())
    num2 = Integer.valueOf(EditText2?.text.toString().intOrString())
```

Comment: Respecto a la primera parte me dices que no es correcto convertir un valor no numérico a uno numérico y perdona mi ignorancia dado que estoy empezando, pero ¿no es para eso para lo que sirve lo de integer.valueOf? y otra cosa te importaria explicarme un poco por encima lo que hace la funcion que me has puesto para solucionar el problema. En cualquier caso gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Claro integer.valueOf() funciona pero no para un valor String que no es numeric por ejemplo "a","?" O en este caso "", estos no son valores numericos.